# Handling specific content type in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a type of file that Chrome will download, but will not display.  I want to create a Chrome extension that can handle this file type.

When someone clicks a link to this file, or tries to go to it directly by URL, how can I intercept the request and display it?

It seems that I can use the `chrome.webRequest` API to intercept network traffic and filter based on the response's `Content-Type`.  However, there is no page or tab which this file is displayed in, so there is nothing to modify for display.

Comment: If this file is linked in a web page, you can intercept `click` event in the web pages using your content script and cancel it and/or redirect it to your extension page. Otherwise you can cancel the request in your webRequest listener and manually open an extension html file where you provide a UI for the file.

Comment: @wOxxOm I don't think the click event is going to work, since I won't know the content type until after the response has started.  I would have to hook the network request and somehow open a new tab.  A bit more detail... I'm working on an extension that can display CBOR-encoded data.  It will function a lot like the JSON formatter extensions.  With those JSON extensions though, the browser actually displays the files as text so there is something to intercept and modify.  For CBOR, the browser just handles it like any other download.

Comment: Well then cancel the request and open an html page in your extension where you'll download the request and present it in your UI.